# iPad App mandatory landscape?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have to develop an app for iPad and the client want only in portrait mode. I read on a forum that all the app for iPad must support both formats portrait & landscape.
   I searched on Apple Guideline and nothing.

This link from Apple Guidelines doesn't specify anything about this "condition":

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just not true, you can support only portrait if that's what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.I'll tell my client that's ok to developp the app only in Portrait Mode.I asked this just for information/confirmation becasue I  was a little confused about this. situation

Answer (score 2):

In project go to Targets  see General tab --->Deployment Info-->Devise Orientations--->Check portrait & uncheck that you didnt need